# Ubuntu One setup interrupted on Windows 7

Tags: installation, ubuntu-one, windows

I was installing the Ubuntu One client, for the first time, on my Windows 7 machine but the process was interrupted before I could enter the SSO validation.

Now, when I start the client and after I have entered my login, nothing happens. I get the following error: u'[my email address]'. Please help, I would like to avoid having to create a new account.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 the credentials can be remove from the Credentials Manager (in the control panel). Go there and check if there are any Ubuntu One creds, if they are, delete them. That should fix the issue.